# DataGridView Row Value Pass to another Page Textedit1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

can you please help regarding the below code i am trying to pass value from DataGridView to the textEdit1 using the below code but its not working please help me. I fill the DataGridView Using SQL query but i cannot pass the row value to the TextEdit.

Code

```
private void DataGridView_DoubleTap(object sender, DataGridGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            int[] selectedRowHandles = DataGridViewEmployee.GetSelectedRows();
            TextEdit1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(DataGridViewEmployee.GetRowCellValue(selectedRowHandles[0], "ID"));


        }
Code: for DataGridView Fill Using SQL Query (Only for Reference):

Code
private void Bind_GVhkCL(string text)
        {
            {
                string query = "SELECT Room_No as 'Room No',Room_Status as 'Room Status', S_Time as 'Start Time',E_Time as 'End Time',c_date as 'Create Date'from HK_Chk " + text;
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                GVhkCL.ItemsSource = dt;
                //GVhkCL.RowHeight = 60; 
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }


        }
```

Comment: XF does not have a DataGrid control.  If you are using a third party control you need to identify which specific control it is.  And "not working" is not a useful description of your problem.  Do you get an error or exception?  Is your even handler firing?  Have you stepped through the code to validate your logic?  Please read [ask] for guidance on writing an on topic question

Comment: Dear Jason I am using Xamarin DevExpress DataGridView control in the Android app

Answer (score 0):

if you take the time to read the DevExpress [docs](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridGestureEventArgs._members#properties), you'll see that `DataGridGestureEventArgs` has a property `Item`

> Gets an object that specifies a data source’s item to which the grid’s
> data row corresponds.

Comment: Dear Mr. Jason,  can you please make one example for me it's 5 to 6 days I am searching and doing coding and logic now my mind stop working.

Comment: `var ID = ((MyClassName)e.Item).ID;`

Comment: what is mean "My Class Name"    please see the mention below my code as per your example i did but its show error private void DataGridView_DoubleTap(object sender, DataGridGestureEventArgs e)
        {

            var ID = ((HKCLViewPage)e.Item).ID;

            Application.Current.Properties["Room No"] = ID;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());

        }

Comment: whatever the type of the object your row is bound to

Comment: Dear Mr. Jason, please see mention below my complete code please let me know where i am doing a mistake:  https://codeshare.io/eVLdB4

Comment: if your `ItemsSource` is a `DataTable`, then I would assume that each row is a `DataRow`.

Comment: I try this one but Mr. Jason still there is error This is error DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no accessible extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'DataRow' could be found

Comment: please take the time to read the docs on DataRow and how to access individual properties